# Math logic versus Semantic Web use of predicate

Tags: predicate-logic

When I see any sort of mathematical logic treatment of a predicate, it typically says something like $G(x)$ where $G$ stands for, e.g. "is the color blue" and the $x$ will be the subject or variable that, when evaluated, becomes a proposition either true or false.

However, the Semantic Web's *[semantic triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_triple)* goes beyond "subject-predicate" and into "subject-predicate-object." For example, *The sky is the color blue* would have *sky* the subject, *is the color* the predicate, and *blue* as the object. Confusing is how the standard math logic I've seen doesn't seem to have the object part, e.g., the subject above would be *sky* and the predicate would just be the entire *is the color blue*, i.e., the object is subsumed by the predicate. Have I simply not found the right logic text -- or is this a real difference not to be overcome?

Comment: The same word can have different meanings. Why should  mathematical logic use the same terminology as the RDF?

Comment: In predicate logic we generalize the natural language word "predicate" to mean not only *unary* predicates $P(x)$ ("x is Blue") but also $n$-ary predicates $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ for $n$ whatever. Example with *arity* two: $x < y$, that is a *binary* predicate. In common language, we call words expressing them *relations*.

Comment: In predicate logic the statement "The color of the sky is blue" will be symbolized with a two-place predicate: $\text {ColorOf}(x,y)$ where the two argument places will be filled with values $\text {Blue}$ and $\text {Sky}$ respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction between "subject" and "object" does not exist in mathematics.

The distinction between subject and object is rather fluid even in natural language. For example, in English, you might say "I like tacos". The subject is "I", and the object is "tacos". In Spanish, the most direct translation of this is "Me gustan los tacos". Here, the subject and the object are flipped; it's actually the thing being liked (the tacos) that is the subject, and the liker (me) which is the object.

In predicate logic, one would simply define a two-place predicate $Likes$, with the semantics that $Likes(a, b)$ means that $a$ likes $b$. There is no grammatical notion in mathematics of one thing "acting on" another; the tacos and I would be treated evenhandedly (we could have just as easily defined $Likes'(a, b) :\equiv Likes(b, a)$).

Comment: Can you suggest a text that expounds on what you're saying?